# Backbone routing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, url-routing

I am creating an app that will list the days of an event as buttons, then let you add dates and click each date to get a new "daily calendar".

This is my first real world app using backbone and underscore, so I keep running into road blocks. I would really appreciate anyone helping me out.

I am now at the point where my collection is full of dates, and I can add to those dates. Now what I am trying to figure out it routing the links to switch out the calendar, depending on the selected date.

Heres what I have relating to this part of the app so far:

**Collections**

```
var Days = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: daysURL
});

var Calendar = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: URL
});
```

**Models**

```
var Header = Backbone.Model.extend();
var header = new Header();

var ConferenceDay = Backbone.Model.extend();
var conferenceDay = new ConferenceDay();
```

**View**

```
 var HeaderView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $(".conf_days"),
  template: _.template($('#days').html()),
  events: {
      'click a.day-link': 'changeDay',
      'click #add_day' : 'addDay',
      'click #previous_day' : 'prevDay',
      'click #next_day' : 'nextDay',
      'click #delete_day' : 'deleteDay'
    },
    initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, "render");
      this.collection = new Days();
      this.collection.fetch();
      this.collection.bind("reset", this.render, this);
    },
    render: function(){
      var JSONdata = this.collection.toJSON();
      this.$el.html(this.template({days: JSONdata}));

      console.log(JSON.stringify(JSONdata))
      return this;

    },
    changeDay: function(e){

      AppRouter.history.navigate($(this).attr('href'));
      return false;

    },
    addDay: function() {
      newDate = Date.parse($('.day-link:first-child').text()).add(1).day();
      var newDay = new  ConferenceDay();
      newDay.set({date_formatted: newDate});

      this.collection.add(newDay)
      newDay.save({
        success: function(){
          alert('yes')
        },
        error: function(){
          alert('no')
        }
      });
    },
    deleteDay: function(event){
      var id = $('.day-link:last-child').data("id");
      $('.day-link:last-child').remove();
    },
    prevDay: function() {

    },
    nextDay: function() {

    },
    loadTimes: function(){
      var html = time.get('times');
      $('.time_td').append(html);
    }

  });
 var headerView = new HeaderView({ model: header });


        ConferenceView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $(".calendar"),
  template: _.template($('#calendar').html()),
  events: {

    },
    initialize: function(){

      //this.listTracks();
      this.collection = new Calendar();
      this.collection.fetch();
      this.collection.bind("reset", this.render, this);
    },
    render: function(){
      var JSONdata = this.collection.toJSON();
      this.$el.html(this.template({days: JSONdata}));
    },

    listTracks: function() {
    }

  });
 var conferenceView = new ConferenceView({model:conferenceDay});
```

**My current routing**

```
 var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
  '' : 'index',
  'day/:id' : 'changeDay'
  },

  initialize: function() {
  },

  index: function() {

  },
  changeDay: function(id){
    alert("changed");
    this.calender.changeDay(id);
    this.dayView = new ConferenceView({model:conferenceDay});
    $('#calender').html(this.dayView.render().el).text('test');
  },
});
 var app = {
 init: function() {
  var routes = new AppRouter();
  Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
  }
}
 app.init();
```

Ideally, I would like the user to click the `day-link` button and have the url update via push state to the `day/:id` and then the `#calender` template would update with the correct model info received from the day update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*There's a lot of code in your post, so I'm not 100% sure the below will cover everything you need to do, but it's a start*

This event handler might be causing some problems:

```
changeDay: function(e){
  AppRouter.history.navigate($(this).attr('href'));
  return false;
}
```

On a detail level, couple of things are off here:

1. You don't need to reference `history`. I'm not sure that the router even has such property. You should call `AppRouter.navigate` instead.
2. If you want the router to trigger your `changeDay` route method, you need to pass an option `trigger:true`, like so:

   ```
   AppRouter.navigate($(this).attr('href'), {trigger:true}).
   ```

**However**, the actual solution is still simpler than that. You can remove the `HeaderView.changeDay` event handler, and the `click a.day-link` event binding from the events hash entirely. Backbone Router will detect the changed URL, and call the router method which matches the new URL automatically.

Comment: ok so my url is setup like `/session/102` points at the app. Then I add `/day/2' to navigate to the 2nd day of the event. The entire URL looks someting like `organizer/sessions/grid/102/day/10`. This should, in turn tell my router, `'day/:id' : 'changeDay'' to call the function `changeDay: function(id){alert("changed");},`. But when I navigate through the links I get no alert! Any ideas of something I could be missing here...?

Comment: Did you tell Backbone that the root of your application is `organizer/sessions/grid/102`? See this: http://backbonejs.org/#History-start "If your application is not being served from the root url / of your domain, be sure to tell History where the root really is, as an option"